# boost::asio error after sending/receiving exactly 128kb

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm developing a client-server app, both sides of which use boost::asio.
I'm trying to send a large package of data over TCP (356 kb)
On server side, I write like:

```
boost::asio::async_write(Msocket, 
    boost::asio::buffer(sendBuffer,dataLen),
    boost::bind(&ServerSession::onDataWrite, 
        this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_trasferred));
```

The onDataWrite is simple:

```
void ServerSession::onDataWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error, const std::size_t bytesSent) {
    if (error) {
        std::cout << "Error " << error << " while sending data" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

On client side:

```
int readSize = ...; // defined from msg header, in this case equals 300 kbytes.
boost::asio::async_read(*Msocket, 
    boost::asio::buffer(recvBuffer, 50*1024*1024),
    boost::asio::transfer_exactly(readSize),
    boost::bind(&ClientSession::onDataRead, 
        this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_trasferred, 
        readSize));
```

And onDataRead is:

```
void ClientSession::onDataRead(const boost::system::error_code& error, const std::size_t bytesRecvd, const int readSize) {
    if (error || bytesRecvd != readSize) {
        std::cout << "Error " << error << " while getting data, expect " << readSize <<", got " << bytesRecvd << std::endl;
    }
}
```

During write, server side prints

```
Error system:10014 while sending data
```

And client prints

```
Error system:0 while getting data, expect 393216, got 131064
```

While 131064 = 128kb - 8 bytes of header.

It looks like this 128-kb issue is caused by send/receive buffer overflow. But I though Boost will take care about those buffers itself, transparently for me.
What do I misunderstand?

Comment: What is `sendBuffer`?

Comment: char*. Generally, it is get like follows

    `class DataBuffer {`

    `private:

        char data[2*1024*1024];

    public:

        char* getBuffer() { return data;}

    }

    void ServerSession::send(){

        char* sendBuffer = Mbuffer.getBuffer();

        ....`

Comment: Is `sendBuffer` a member of the same class that owns the socket?

Comment: sendBuffer is a local variable. Mbuffer is a member of the same SeverSession class that owns the Msocket.
Sorry, the code above is not completely correct.
There is no 'sendBuffer' variable, instead, the sending buffer in async_write is formed like
`boost::asio::buffer(Mbuffer.getBuffer(), Mbuffer.getSize())`

Comment: The error code suggests something is going wrong with the allocation of the buffer.

Comment: OMG! Thank you, David! I've been looking at different point!
For some reason, I did not look at the error code attentively=) I thought it's 100<5>4 and thought the client disconnects itself.
10014 is indeed different. 
Shame on me=) I'll google the issue now.

Comment: You can just print `error.message()` instead of `error` so you get readable information...

Comment: @thedimitrius ping? Any news? Can we close this question?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved.
It was in the fact that during heavy load the Mbuffer member variable was overwritten a couple of times (i.e. the send() was called several times) before the message was actually sent.